# Play! PessimisticLockException after Re-Compiling

Tags: java, hibernate, playframework

I'm currently using Java Play 2.0.1, and the h2 memory database.

I presently display all items contained in the database displayed in a table on one of my pages, and this works fine, including CRUD operations. However, when I delete all items contained in the database, and then modify my code in some way (just to re-compile and reload the page, for example adding comments), when I attempt to display the page where the database items are displayed I am thrown the exception:

```
PessimisticLockException: Timeout trying to lock table
```

From the line

```
x = entityManager.createQuery("FROM X").getResultList();
```

My delete method:

```
@Transactional
  public static Result deleteEvent(Long hjid){
      entityManager.remove(entityManager.find(X.class, hjid));
      flash("success", "Event has been deleted");
      return redirect(routes.Application.events());
  }
```

Now I've tried modifying my `db.default.url="jdbc:h2:mem:events` with LOCK_TIMEOUT in my application.conf, as well as setting MVCC=TRUE, but the exception is still thrown.

What I potentially think could be the issue is that I declare my EntityManager as a static field

```
static EntityManager entityManager = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
```

Though I am not certain if this is the cause for the error, or if it is just a poor idea and bad practice or neither.

Question is, why is the Exception being thrown only after re-compiling and loading the page?